# Whats the error in this Python(2.7) code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a code to get the service code of any kind of URL

```
import requests
req = requests.get("http://www.google.com", allow_redirects = False)
code_from_url = req.status_code
print type(code_from_url)
codes = { 200:'Success', 301:'Moved Permanently', 400: 'Bad Request', 401:'Unauthorized', 403:'Forbidden', 404:'Not Found', 500:'Internal Server Error', 502:'Bad Gateway' }
print code_from_url
print codes[code_from_url]
```

But when I run this code I get an error on line 7 i.e. `print codes[code_from_url]` stating 'KeyError: 302'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your lookup collection (slightly reformatted):

```
codes = {
    200: 'Success',
    301: 'Moved Permanently',
    400: 'Bad Request',
    401: 'Unauthorized',
    403: 'Forbidden',
    404: 'Not Found',
    500: 'Internal Server Error',
    502: 'Bad Gateway'
}
```

actually *has* no key of `302`, *that's* you are getting the `KeyError` exception.

Code `302 Found` is meant to indicate to a client that a redirection is needed, while providing the ability for said client to update its own references to the resource. So there's (at least) three ways to handle this problem.

---

First option, if you don't actually care that you're being redirected (and you probably don't for `http://www.google.com` so this would be my preferred option), you can simply let the redirect happen without notification:

```
req = requests.get("http://www.google.com", allow_redirects = True)
```

---

Second, you can treat `302` as an error by adding it to your response collection:

```
codes = { 200:'Success', 301:'Moved Permanently', 302:'Found', ...
```

---

Thirdly, you can check for this `302` code and treat it as a special case, i.e., not as an error.